# JpGraph LinePlot output exceeds graph area when using SetScale

Tags: php, graphing, jpgraph

I'm using [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) to graph some data. When I use the SetScale function to force a y-axis range the output visually overflows the graph area. I would like to have the output cropped to the graph area.

```
<?php

require_once ('include/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('include/jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');

$datay1 = array(20,7,16,46,90,5,0,5,95);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(400,300);
$graph->title->Set('Graph Title');
$graph->title->font_size = 20;
$graph->SetScale("textlin",20,50);

//this version works but does not set the y-axis scale
//$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);

// Output line
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

This is the current output:
[image]

This is the desired output (rendered by Excel):
[image]

Comment: I've looked into this and can't find an answer, so +1'ed.  I'm curious now, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with the company behind JpGraph and they were able to help. The missing option is:

```
$graph->setClipping(true);
```

I hope this helps anyone else who may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myMaxY = 50; //You need to set Y Max as you want

$length = count($datay1);

for($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++)
{
    if($datay1[$i] > $myMaxY)
       $datay1[$i] = $myMaxY;
} 

$graph->SetScale("textlin",20,$myMaxY); //Dont forget to change this
```